# WCF Successful response always returns NULL

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service endpoint in my C# application. The response from service is always null for successful response.

If I pass an invalid parameter the error from service is correct which implies that the calls are going to service.  I also connected with the service owner and they tracked the response on their(WCF endpoint) side , they can see proper response getting generated but the same response is not reaching the application from where it is being invoked. This behavior is for all the methods in that service. I don't get any error as well. I verified with SOAP UI tool where I get the correct(valid) response.

[image: Screen Shot of success response]

[image]

[image: Code Snippet]

I have added the code snippet , it's simple console app from where I am invoking the WCF endpoint . The success and failure response are also attached.

[image]

Comment: Actually, I think you need to test the WCF service. You mentioned that you didn't get any errors. Could it be that your WCF service returned NULL? If you can provide some code, I think it will help me a lot to help you solve the problem.

Comment: We did check on service end and the response there is generated but at our end it is null always. Just to add when I pass a wrong parameter a valid exception is thrown.

Comment: In fact, without code, I can't determine where the error is.

Comment: Have added the snippets.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't describe it clearly. The code you give is the calling code on the server side, and in fact I can't test it based on this code. I think your test direction can be placed as follows:1.Whether there is a problem with this service itself; 2.Whether there is a problem with the transfer. However, I think the second possibility is relatively unlikely.

Comment: I'd like to take a look at the config file and code of WCF if I can. Because this can help me test.

Comment: have added the config snippet . I dont have WCF code and i dont think that there is any problem with that because the same service is working with another code base which is in C# only.

Comment: I just looked at the calls in fiddler and to my surprise even fiddler is showing the correct response.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I think you can use another way to receive this service.

Right click on 'Solution' - 'Add' - 'Service Reference'.

As long as your service is online, enter a URL to connect to the service.

When you connect to the service, your client's app.config is changed.

For example:

[image]

[image]